# how to test if a number is divisible by a decimal less than 1? (54.10 % .10)

Tags: python, decimal, division, modulus

I'm trying to test if a `float` i.e(`54.10`) is divisible by `0.10`.  `54.10 % .10` returns `.10` and not `0`, why is that and how can I get it to do what I want it to do?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module to avoid the floating point precision problem:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('54.10') % decimal.Decimal('0.10')
Decimal('0.00')
```

Comment: Actually since Decimal slowed the program down so much, I've decided to just test the last digit in string form: str(54.10)[-1] == '0'

Comment: Please keep in mind that, when declaring the Decimal numbers in the above solution, you use a string input, such as decimal.Decimal(str(54.10)) & Decimal(str(0.10)), otherwise the result will not be Decimal('0.00'), it will instead be Decimal('0.09999999999999842348330503228'). 

"Construction from an integer or a float performs an exact conversion of the value of that integer or float." - https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial

Answer (score 5):

The tried and true method here is to multiply your divisor and dividend by a power of 10. Effectively,  54.10 becomes 541 and 0.10 becomes 1. Then you can use standard modulo or ceiling and floor to achieve what you need.