# Check if a number is divisible by another in python

Tags: python, math

I would like to check the following

This settings work

```
number = 100
divisor = 10
```

These do not

```
number = 100
divisor = 0.1
```

Scenario 1 shows correct answer however Scenario 2 does not. What would be the best way to have this show correct result.

```
def isDivisible(number, divisor):
    return (number % divisor)

number = 100
divisor = 10

print("Scenario 1:")
print("")
print("Number = " + str(number))
print("Divisor = " + str(divisor))
print("")
print("Answer:")
if isDivisible(number, divisor) == 0:
    print("Answer: True")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))
else:
    print("Answer: False")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))

print("")
print("##################")
print("")

number = 100
divisor = 0.1

print("Scenario 2:")
print("")
print("Number = " + str(number))
print("Divisor = " + str(divisor))
print("")
print("Answer:")
if isDivisible(number, divisor) == 0:
    print("Answer: True")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))
else:
    print("Answer: False")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))

print("")
```

Comment: If you only have tests where `True` is the answer, the implementation can just be  `return True`.

Comment: You should show examples that fail.

Comment: Modulo does not work for floating point. You need to find a way to convert to integer first. And that might be a real problem. Consider 1 % 0,1428571428571429. Will it be divisable? Yes, if you consider 0,14... to be 1/7. No, if you truncate after the last digit.

Comment: Will update and post some examples

Comment: @ThomasWeller ok ill keep at it will update with answer if i manage to work it out cheers for you input about converting to integer

Answer (score 3):

Based on your examples, you're using floating point numbers. Floating point numbers have a lot of limitations--most importantly, they are limited in their precision. To be frank, I'm surprised floating point modulus even *works.* It should probably be a `TypeError`.

Try using the [decimal package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) from the Python standard library and see if you have more success.

Comment: There's an example here on how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064393.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is correct answer but seems to work fine. I converted to decimal using number as a string. I tried just using decimal without converting to string however i got a lot of junk on the end of "number" variable so it didn't work out.

```
from decimal import Decimal # Added this

def isDivisible(number, divisor):
    return (number % divisor)

number = 10
divisor = 0.0001
divisor = Decimal(str(divisor))
number = Decimal(str(number))

print("Number = " + str(number)) # Added this
print("Divisor = " + str(divisor)) # Added this
print("")
if isDivisible(number, divisor) == 0:
    print("Answer: True")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))
else:
    print("Answer: False")
    print("Value: " + str(isDivisible(number, divisor)))

print("")
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. When you set `divisor = 0.0001`, you're already creating a floating-point value that carries the normal caveats of floating point (e.g. limited precision). You need to write it _directly_ as a Decimal, with it never becoming a binary floating point value at all, e.g. `Decimal("0.0001")`.

Comment: @asthasr Problem is the rest of the code/program is using floating numbers all through it. Thanks for the tip though if its not 100% the way it should be done ill try get rid of the floating numbers. Cheers